# Looping requests doesn't execute requests in a sequential manner

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

It runs without any errors but the requests output is in an asynchronous manner.

The desired output that I want is that for every url in the for loop in after_timeline function,further functions are called 
and then return back and further calls functions and so on. But now results are irregular means the result for third url is displayed first and also some results are also missing.Please help me?

```
def scroll_page(self,response):
        timeline_url = response.xpath("//div[@class='cr d cg']/a/@href").extract_first()
        new_timeline = response.urljoin(timeline_url)
        yield scrapy.Request(url=new_timeline,callback=self.after_timeline)

    def after_timeline(self,response):
        photos_url = response.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Full Story')]/@href").extract()
        for photo in photos_url:
            new_story_url = "https://mobile.facebook.com" + photo
            yield scrapy.Request(url=new_story_url,callback=self.after_story)

    def after_story(self,response):
        friend_page = response.xpath("//a[@class='_45m8']/@href").extract_first()
        global no_likes
        no_likes = response.xpath("//div[@class='_1g06']/text()").extract_first()
        #https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/yv/r/dOJFaVZihS_.png
        new_friend_url = "https://mobile.facebook.com" + friend_page
        yield scrapy.Request(url=new_friend_url,callback=self.friends)


    def friends(self,response):
        #top_conn ={}
        friend_list = response.xpath("//h3[@class='bd']").extract()
        #print(friend_list)
        for friend in friend_list:
            sel = Selector(text=friend)
            fbid= sel.xpath(".//a/@href").extract_first(),
            name= sel.xpath(".//a/text()").extract_first()
            print(name)
        print(response.url)
        para = '?limit=200'
        #print(para)
        #inspect_response(response, self)
        url = response.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'See more')]/parent::*/@href").extract_first()
        if url is not None:
            url=url.replace("?limit=10",para)
            kaint_url = "https://mobile.facebook.com" + url
            yield scrapy.Request(url=kaint_url,callback=self.fetch_fr)

    def fetch_fr(self,response):
        friend_list = response.xpath("//h3[@class='bd']").extract()
        for friend in friend_list:
            sel = Selector(text=friend)
            fbid= sel.xpath(".//a/@href").extract_first(),
            name= sel.xpath(".//a/text()").extract_first()
            print(name)
        print(response.url)
```

Comment: This is the default and expected behavior of scrapy, if you want to get the result in order you'll have to write your own output processing middleware btw currently you are not outputting any data, you are just printing it, try to yield data

Comment: as I know it may display in different order but it may save in file in correct order.  BTW: it may run threads in different order because system runs many other threads and it may decide which thread run as first and scrapy uses random sleep time to better simulate human behavior.